# Preventing duplicate listeners on a page

Tags: javascript

If a few people work on the same page, what is a good way to prevent duplicate listeners? I was thinking to create a "master" JS file for each page which will expose the needed listeners, then whoever need to use that will use these instead of creating a duplicate listener.

This is most likely only matters for some global targets like `window` or `document` and not the specific listeners that are set by very specific selectors.

For example, if I need a `focus` event listener on the window, I create:

```
// myScript.js

window.addEventListener("focus", (event) => {
    // some code here
});
```

But another dev can also create his own script and add his own listener on that page:

```
// otherScript.js

window.addEventListener("focus", (event) => {
    // some code here
});
```

What is a good way to prevent these duplicates and avoid collisions? I was thinking maybe it's possible to store those global listeners (`window`, `document`, etc..) in a master JS file and save the listener handler on a variable and then it can be reused?

Something like:

```
let globalWindowFocusListener = window.addEventListener("focus", (event) => { ...
```

(I am not sure about the syntax or if that's possible, just wrote a general idea)

Or that's not correct and there are other ways to do it?

Comment: What's the problem with having multiple listeners? They'll presumably do different things since they're from different scripts. Unlike the old-school `.onfocus` and so on, you absolutely can have multiple event listener functions for the same event.

Comment: If I have the same listener from 2 different scripts on the same page, for example the `focus` on the window, and each does different thing - they won't both be triggered?

Comment: Both will be triggered, one after the other.

Comment: Yes and as you said there is no problem in having multiple in terms of performance? Then it's OK, I should then delete this post. thank you

Comment: *"each does different thing - they won't both be triggered?"* Simple test proves that statement is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a problem with having two handlers for the same event; they'll be called one after the other when the event fires.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("x");
const textarea = document.getElementById("y");

// Script 1
button.addEventListener("click", () => textarea.value += "Ding!\n");

// Script 2
button.addEventListener("click", () => textarea.value += "Dong!\n");
textarea.addEventListener("focus", () => textarea.value += "Ooh, that tickles!\n");
```

```html
<button id="x">Click me!</button>
<br>
<textarea id="y" rows=10 cols=30 readonly></textarea>
```

Answer (score -5):

Indeed, multiple listeners waste resources and slow the page down.
Ever wonder why YouTube, Reddit; and many other overzealous websites, are so slow and frustrating?

They have too many elements and too many listeners wasting memory and preoccupying the processor!

They’re great examples of how NOT to code, and I don’t care how popular they may be because they’re still badly written.

What you can do is create a separate ***Listen.js*** file that holds all the listeners so that anyone can quickly look through and see what already exists, which you can easily link to in your .htm pages like this...

```
<script src="Listen.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm a browser author and I can tell you're not. :)

Comment: Soon they’ll introduce memory limits per-tab and you’ll see them all scrambling to rewrite their pages! :)

Comment: Your advice is something I would expect in 1999. lol, but according to you which has a one day old account, I have no clue what I am talking about.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I used your answer but named my file `<script src="ListenHereYou.js"></script>`

Comment: @Stackerito You should not use this answer... Multiple downvotes should clearly show you this is a bad advice.

Comment: @epascarello It was a joke . I think the guy who wrote the answer also created an account for the joke